# JsonSerializationException for type with private constructor

Tags: serialization, json.net, ravendb, nlog

I am persisting `NLog` logging statements to my `RavenDb` database. The `LogEventInfo` class, which represents a log statement, has a property, `LogLevel`, with a private constructor. Instances of `LogLevel` (Info, Warn, etc.) are created via static, readonly properties that call the private constructor.

The problem is that I wish to read the messages out of the database and querying for them is throwing a `Json.Net` serialization error:

> Unable to find a constructor to use for type NLog.LogLevel. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path 'Level.Name'.

How can I get around the error? Could creating some kind of Raven index help here?

Comment: You can write a custom `JsonConverter` if you like, or you can do like Xharze said and use your own class for the log data instead of storing the NLog classes directly.

Comment: I'm leaning towards a custom class. Given the way that `LogLevel` is designed, I'd have to ignore it during deserialization, which I don't want to do as it's a key piece of logging info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this, is to create a custom class to hold all the log information.

Answer (score 1):

It worked with me like this

[create a CustomCreationConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomCreationConverter.htm) and use it with your object's deserialization

```
public class EventInfoConverter : CustomCreationConverter<LogEventInfo>
    {
        private string _level { get; set; }
        public EventInfoConverter(string s)
        {
            JToken eventinfo = JObject.Parse(s);
            var childs = eventinfo.Children();
            foreach (var item in childs)
            {
                if (((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty)item).Name == "Level")
                {
                    var m = ((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty)item).Value.Children();
                    foreach (var item1 in m)
                    {
                        _level = ((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty)item1).Value.ToString();
                        break;
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public override LogEventInfo Create(Type objectType)
        {
            LogEventInfo eventInfo = new LogEventInfo();
            switch (_level)
            {
                case "Info":
                         eventInfo = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Info, "", "");
                    break;
                case "Debug":
                    eventInfo = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Debug, "", "");
                    break;
                case "Error":
                    eventInfo = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Error, "", "");
                    break;
                case "Warn":
                    eventInfo = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Warn, "", "");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return eventInfo;
        }
    }
```

- In your deserialization:

  ```
  NLog.Logger _logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
  _logger.Log(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LogEventInfo>(eventInfo, new EventInfoConverter(eventInfo)));
  ```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18218729)

Comment: Thanks yivi,Noted!