# JsonSerializationException: Unable to find a constructor to use for type ... Path 'data', line 1, position 83

Tags: c#, list, serialization, asp.net-core, json.net

This is my Json String returned from my webapi wroten by ASP.NET Core 2.0:

```
{
    "httpStatusCode": 200,
    "isSuccess": true,
    "errorCode": null,
    "errorDetail": null,
    "data": []
}
```

In my client I use Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize the JsonString.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonMessage<T>>(jsonString);
```

In `JsonMessage` the `T` is `PageList`, In `Pagelist` the `T` is `Team`.

Is it too many level?

But there is a exception that:

> JsonSerializationException: Unable to find a constructor to use for
>   type Tower.Abstraction.PagedList`1[Tower.Abstraction.Model.Team]. Path
>   'data', line 1, position 83.
>   JsonSerializationException: Unable to find a constructor to use for type Tower.Abstraction.PagedList`1[Tower.Abstraction.Model.Team]. Path 'data', line 1, position 83.

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewList(JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, out bool createdFromNonDefaultCreator)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, object existingValue, string id)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, object target)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, string id)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, object existingValue)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, bool checkAdditionalContent)
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(string value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
```

It works well when the data is not PagedList.

The class structure:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace Tower.Web
{
    [Serializable]
    [DataContract]
    public class JsonMessage<T>
    {
        [DataMember]
        public HttpStatusCode HttpStatusCode { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string ErrorDetail { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public T Data { get; set; }
    }
}


[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class PagedList<T> : List<T>
{
    [DataMember]
    public long TotalCount { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int PageIndex { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public class Team : Base
{
    [Required]
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public Guid TeamId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public decimal TimeZone { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string TeamDescription { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Guid AdminUserId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show us your code and also the class structure.

Comment: Any chance you could share a [mcve] with JSON and c# types that reproduce the problem?  The exception means that Json.NET could not choose a constructor with which to construct one of your types; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28155169) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15327589/3744182) for other examples.  But we need to see your actual types to know the exact problem.

Comment: Hi @RawitasKrungkaew, I added my class structure.

Comment: Hmmm, duplicate of [Deserializing an IEnumerable<T> with `[DataContract]` applied does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35778811/3744182) perhaps?

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my current setup.  Can you share 1) The type `T` passed to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonMessage<T>>(jsonString);`?  2) The full `ToString()` output of the exception including the traceback, exception type, message and inner exception?

Comment: @dbc this is the full output string (as the JsonMessage<T> generated from the ASP.NET Core Web Api): {"httpStatusCode":200,"isSuccess":true,"errorCode":null,"errorDetail":null,"data":[]}

Answer (score 2):

use Attribute [JsonConstructor] in empty constructor

```
public class QuestionModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string CorrectAnswer { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string IncorrectAnswers { get; set; }
    [JsonConstructor]
    public QuestionModel() { }
}
```