# How do I deserialize a paging object in C# .Net Core

Tags: c#, serialization, redis, json.net

I have a string (stored in Redis) and I need  to deserialize it to an object like this:

```
public class PagedList<T>
{
    public int TotalItems { get; }
    public int PageNumber { get; }
    public int PageSize { get; }
    public List<T> List { get; }

    //public PagedList() { }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public PagedList(IEnumerable<T> source, int totalRecord, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
        TotalItems = totalRecord;
        PageNumber = pageNumber;
        PageSize = pageSize;
        List = source.ToList();
    }

    //[JsonConstructor]
    public PagedList(IQueryable<T> source, int totalRecord, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
        TotalItems = totalRecord;
        PageNumber = pageNumber;
        PageSize = pageSize;
        List = source.ToList();
    }

    public int TotalPages => (int)Math.Ceiling(this.TotalItems / (double)this.PageSize);

    public PagingHeader GetHeader()
    {
        return new PagingHeader(this.TotalItems, this.PageNumber, this.PageSize, this.TotalPages);
    }
}
```

The string is:

```
{
  "TotalItems": 63,
  "PageNumber": 1,
  "PageSize": 2147483646,
  "List": [
    {
      "Id": 6,
      "Tendvhc": "Tỉnh Lào Cai",
      "Parentid": null,
      "Matinh": "10",
      "Mahuyen": "000",
      "Maxa": "00000",
      "Status": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using this in my code, but getting error:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString)
```

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Unable to find a constructor to use for type GIS.CQRS.Queries.PagedList`1[iNRES.Service.Category.Domain.Models.Dvhc]. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path 'TotalItems', line 1, position 14.
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonS

How can I deal with complex object like above?

Comment: I *suspect* if you renamed the parameters to match the properties they're assigning, it may well just work. You can't expect Json.NET to just "know" that a parameter named "source" corresponds to a property named "List".

Comment: You can use `JsonPropertyAttribute name` to change the property name at deserialization [ref](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm). A valid Json string should be a nice add for it to be a [mre]

Comment: related : [JsonSerializationException: Unable to find a constructor to use for type …](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47804916/jsonserializationexception-unable-to-find-a-constructor-to-use-for-type-pat)

Comment: @JonSkeet I just have tried this code, but didnt work: ```[JsonConstructor]
        public PagedList(List<T> List, int TotalItems, int PageNumber, int PageSize)
        {
            this.TotalItems = TotalItems;
            this.PageNumber = PageNumber;
            this.PageSize = PageSize;
            this.List = List;
        }```

Comment: The constructor parameter names should be camelCase, not PascalCase

Comment: @JonasHøgh Didnt work. ```[JsonConstructor]
        public PagedList(List<T> list, int totalItems, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
        {
            this.TotalItems = totalItems;
            this.PageNumber = pageNumber;
            this.PageSize = pageSize;
            this.List = list;
        }```

Comment: "didn't work" doesn't give us much information. Is it exactly the same error? Something slightly different?

Comment: I just have fixed the problem. @JonSkeet

Answer (score 1):

I have just fixed this problem by:

using

```
using JsonConstructorAttribute = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConstructorAttribute;
```

instead of

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
```

and adding this constructor

```
[JsonConstructor]
public PagedList(List<T> list, int totalItems, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
{
    this.TotalItems = totalItems;
    this.PageNumber = pageNumber;
    this.PageSize = pageSize;
    this.List = list;
}
```